# UIPickerViewDelegate Methods Not Getting Called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I have created a custom view that contains a `UIPickerView` and a `UITableViewCell` to display the contents currently selected in the picker. My `PickerViewController` is set as both the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the picker, and I have implemented `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:`, `pickerView: numberOfRowsInComponent:`, and `pickerView: titleForRow: forComponent:`, but the picker appears blank when the program is run, and thanks to placing `NSLog` calls in the methods, I've discovered that the methods are never getting called. I have no idea what the issue is, as the picker appears to be linked up correctly with the `PickerViewController`.

For the basic functionality that I'm trying to achieve, look at the "Start & End" view in the iOS Calendar app. I am trying to imitate this exactly, but only using one `UITableViewCell` instead of three.

**PickerViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *pickerSelection;
// Property to dynamically determine what content to display in the picker.
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsChoosingClass;

@end
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(self.thePicker.delegate.description);
    if (self.userIsChoosingClass) {
        self.pickerSelection.textLabel.text = @"Class";
    } else {
        self.pickerSelection.textLabel.text = @"Major";
    }
}
```

**Picker View Data Source Methods**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    size_t numberOfRows = 0;

    if (self.userIsChoosingClass) {
        numberOfRows = [self.brain classChoicesForSignUp].count;
    } else {
        numberOfRows = [self.brain majorChoicesForSignUp].count;
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

**Picker View Delegate Methods**

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"Picker view delegate method called");
    NSString *title;

    if (self.userIsChoosingClass) {
        title = [[self.brain classChoicesForSignUp] objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
        title = [self.majorChoices objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    return title;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your numberOfRows... datasource method is returning 0, then your delegate method will never be called - the picker won't ask for the title of a row if it doesn't think it has any rows to display.